# Master method for multiple primitive arguments in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters, primitive-types

Say i have these methods:

```
public void doSomethingInteger(int i){...}
public void doSomethingByte(byte b){...}
public void doSomethingFloat(float f){...}
public void doSomethingDouble(double d){...}
```

All of them perform the same action, just accept variables in different formats.

Instead of ReWriting the code for each method to use a different variable, is there a way to write one method that I can call from each of these methods?

Comment: The details will likely depend on code that you've not shown us. We've no idea what your method should be doing, so I don't imagine any of us can help you based on the information posted so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting. You probably want to put the implementation in `doSomethingDouble()`. Then you can define the other methods as :

```
public void doSomethingInteger(int i) {doSomethingDouble((double)i;}
public void doSomethingByte(byte b) {doSomethingDouble((double)b;}
public void doSomethingFloat(float f) {doSomethingDouble((double)f;}
```

Those are all [widening conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), so you are not losing any information.

> 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> ```
> **byte to** short, int, long, float, or **double**
>
> short to int, long, float, or double
>
> char to int, long, float, or double
>
> **int to** long, float, or **double**
>
> long to float or double
>
> **float to double**
> ```
>
> A widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value.
>
> A widening primitive conversion from an integral type to another
>   integral type, or from float to double in a strictfp expression
>   (§15.4), does not lose any information at all; the numeric value is
>   preserved exactly.

Comment: Thank you, i was not sure if double would be able to hold all the other primitives!

Comment: There's **no need** to cast here.

Comment: @user3718550 All those conversions to double are widening conversions, so there's no problem.

Comment: "Not losing information" is false -- `long` to `double` loses precision on values above `2^53`.  The key phrase is "the overall magnitude", but small bits lose precision.

Comment: @LouisWasserman nobody was talking about a long to double conversion. only int,byte,float to double.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write

```
void doSomething(double d) {
```

All the other numeric types; `byte, short, char, int, long, float` will be widened to a `double`